# Drawing in a PDF file

Tags: php, pdf, github, drawing

I would like to draw in a PDF file.

Example: Open the PDF file and get such drawing tools like circle, square, text etc... Using these tools will draw shapes on the PDF file.

I searched on google and found such options like pdf.js. But it's not implemented in core PHP or normal MVC structure. It's implemented in JavaScript.

Any alternative for pdf.js to draw the shape in a PDF file?

I am looking for the same as the [example shown here](http://tech.chitgoks.com/2016/03/06/annotationeer-my-web-application-that-can-create-annotations-in-pdf-js/).

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are *off-topic* for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Thank's ahamed for edit the question

Comment: you certainly cannot do it in php except to save and load those annotations to your pdf reader. also, pdf.js is just a pdf viewer. it can display annotations created in the pdf but it cannot create annotations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Last year when I came upon the same problem I researched and after some tweaking and adjustments I managed to make it work. So here's a detailed explanation on how to set up and use my method.

I'm using a combination of two libraries:

- [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/): (**F**ree **P**ortable **D**ocument **F**ormat) which allows to generate PDF files with PHP
- [FPDI](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/): (**F**ree **P**ortable **D**ocument **I**mporter) which uses existing PDF and converts them to templates to used by FPDF

First, you'll need to download the two libraries: FPDF is found [here](http://www.fpdf.org/) in the download section and FPDI is on [this page](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/downloads/#p-97). You will be given two folders. Go ahead and add them to your project.

Here's my directory structure:

[image]

Let's go in `index.php` (or any other file for that matter) and edit a PDF file that we'll name `sample.pdf`. I had found some code from the [official documentation](https://manuals.setasign.com/fpdi-manual/v1/the-fpdi-class/examples/#index-4) but actually did some modifications to simplify it.
You will see I have added the method `nextPage()` to the `PDF` class to make the navigation between pages easier.

```
<?php
require_once('FPDF/fpdf.php');
require_once('FPDI/fpdi.php');

// path of PDF file
$fullPathToFile = "sample.pdf";


class PDF extends FPDI {

    var $fileIndex;
    var $currentPage = 1;

    function Header() {

        global $fullPathToFile;

        if (is_null($this->fileIndex)) {

            $this->numPages = $this->setSourceFile($fullPathToFile);
            $this->fileIndex = $this->importPage(1);

        } $this->useTemplate($this->fileIndex, 0, 0,200);

    }

    function nextPage() {

        if($this->currentPage != 1) {
            $this->fileIndex = $this->importPage($this->currentPage);
        }
        $this->addPage();

        return ++$this->currentPage;
    }

}

// initiate PDF
$pdf = new PDF();

// go to first page
$pdf->nextPage();

// add content to current page
$pdf->SetFont("helvetica", "", 20);
$pdf->SetTextColor(220, 20, 60);
$pdf->Text(50, 20, "I should not be here!");

// move to next page and add content
$pdf->nextPage();

$pdf->SetFont("arial", "", 15);
$pdf->SetTextColor(65, 105, 225);
$pdf->Text(50, 20, "Me neither!!!");

//show the PDF in page
$pdf->Output();
```

The `Output()` method can receive different arguments: you can simply output the PDF file in a frame or you can force the download of the PDF file to the user's computer. [Read here](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm) for more information on that.

DEMO!
[image]

FPDF's community has written several scripts one of which might interest you:
 it's the **[geometric figures](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script69.php)** FPDF plugin (id `script69.php`). It allows you to draw lines, rectangles, curves, ellipses, circles, polygon among others.

---

Here's a bonus for you:

Create a new file called `draw.php` and put the source code provided on [here](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script69.php). I have provided the source code below **(the first three lines are different than the original source code to make it work)**.

```
<?php
require_once('FPDF/fpdf.php');
require_once('FPDI/fpdi.php');

class PDF_Draw extends FPDI {
    // Sets line style
    // Parameters:
    // - style: Line style. Array with keys among the following:
    //   . width: Width of the line in user units
    //   . cap: Type of cap to put on the line (butt, round, square). The difference between 'square' and 'butt' is that 'square' projects a flat end past the end of the line.
    //   . join: miter, round or bevel
    //   . dash: Dash pattern. Is 0 (without dash) or array with series of length values, which are the lengths of the on and off dashes.
    //           For example: (2) represents 2 on, 2 off, 2 on , 2 off ...
    //                        (2,1) is 2 on, 1 off, 2 on, 1 off.. etc
    //   . phase: Modifier of the dash pattern which is used to shift the point at which the pattern starts
    //   . color: Draw color. Array with components (red, green, blue)
    function SetLineStyle($style) {
        extract($style);
        if (isset($width)) {
            $width_prev = $this->LineWidth;
            $this->SetLineWidth($width);
            $this->LineWidth = $width_prev;
        }
        if (isset($cap)) {
            $ca = array('butt' => 0, 'round'=> 1, 'square' => 2);
            if (isset($ca[$cap]))
                $this->_out($ca[$cap] . ' J');
        }
        if (isset($join)) {
            $ja = array('miter' => 0, 'round' => 1, 'bevel' => 2);
            if (isset($ja[$join]))
                $this->_out($ja[$join] . ' j');
        }
        if (isset($dash)) {
            $dash_string = '';
            if ($dash) {
                $tab = explode(',', $dash);
                $dash_string = '';
                foreach ($tab as $i => $v) {
                    if ($i > 0)
                        $dash_string .= ' ';
                    $dash_string .= sprintf('%.2F', $v);
                }
            }
            if (!isset($phase) || !$dash)
                $phase = 0;
            $this->_out(sprintf('[%s] %.2F d', $dash_string, $phase));
        }
        if (isset($color)) {
            list($r, $g, $b) = $color;
            $this->SetDrawColor($r, $g, $b);
        }
    }

    // Draws a line
    // Parameters:
    // - x1, y1: Start point
    // - x2, y2: End point
    // - style: Line style. Array like for SetLineStyle
    function Line($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $style = null) {
        if ($style)
            $this->SetLineStyle($style);
        parent::Line($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2);
    }

    // Draws a rectangle
    // Parameters:
    // - x, y: Top left corner
    // - w, h: Width and height
    // - style: Style of rectangle (draw and/or fill: D, F, DF, FD)
    // - border_style: Border style of rectangle. Array with some of this index
    //   . all: Line style of all borders. Array like for SetLineStyle
    //   . L: Line style of left border. null (no border) or array like for SetLineStyle
    //   . T: Line style of top border. null (no border) or array like for SetLineStyle
    //   . R: Line style of right border. null (no border) or array like for SetLineStyle
    //   . B: Line style of bottom border. null (no border) or array like for SetLineStyle
    // - fill_color: Fill color. Array with components (red, green, blue)
    function Rect($x, $y, $w, $h, $style = '', $border_style = null, $fill_color = null) {
        if (!(false === strpos($style, 'F')) && $fill_color) {
            list($r, $g, $b) = $fill_color;
            $this->SetFillColor($r, $g, $b);
        }
        switch ($style) {
            case 'F':
                $border_style = null;
                parent::Rect($x, $y, $w, $h, $style);
                break;
            case 'DF': case 'FD':
                if (!$border_style || isset($border_style['all'])) {
                    if (isset($border_style['all'])) {
                        $this->SetLineStyle($border_style['all']);
                        $border_style = null;
                    }
                } else
                    $style = 'F';
                parent::Rect($x, $y, $w, $h, $style);
                break;
            default:
                if (!$border_style || isset($border_style['all'])) {
                    if (isset($border_style['all']) && $border_style['all']) {
                        $this->SetLineStyle($border_style['all']);
                        $border_style = null;
                    }
                    parent::Rect($x, $y, $w, $h, $style);
                }
                break;
        }
        if ($border_style) {
            if (isset($border_style['L']) && $border_style['L'])
                $this->Line($x, $y, $x, $y + $h, $border_style['L']);
            if (isset($border_style['T']) && $border_style['T'])
                $this->Line($x, $y, $x + $w, $y, $border_style['T']);
            if (isset($border_style['R']) && $border_style['R'])
                $this->Line($x + $w, $y, $x + $w, $y + $h, $border_style['R']);
            if (isset($border_style['B']) && $border_style['B'])
                $this->Line($x, $y + $h, $x + $w, $y + $h, $border_style['B']);
        }
    }

    // Draws a Bézier curve (the Bézier curve is tangent to the line between the control points at either end of the curve)
    // Parameters:
    // - x0, y0: Start point
    // - x1, y1: Control point 1
    // - x2, y2: Control point 2
    // - x3, y3: End point
    // - style: Style of rectangule (draw and/or fill: D, F, DF, FD)
    // - line_style: Line style for curve. Array like for SetLineStyle
    // - fill_color: Fill color. Array with components (red, green, blue)
    function Curve($x0, $y0, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $x3, $y3, $style = '', $line_style = null, $fill_color = null) {
        if (!(false === strpos($style, 'F')) && $fill_color) {
            list($r, $g, $b) = $fill_color;
            $this->SetFillColor($r, $g, $b);
        }
        switch ($style) {
            case 'F':
                $op = 'f';
                $line_style = null;
                break;
            case 'FD': case 'DF':
                $op = 'B';
                break;
            default:
                $op = 'S';
                break;
        }
        if ($line_style)
            $this->SetLineStyle($line_style);

        $this->_Point($x0, $y0);
        $this->_Curve($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $x3, $y3);
        $this->_out($op);
    }

    // Draws an ellipse
    // Parameters:
    // - x0, y0: Center point
    // - rx, ry: Horizontal and vertical radius (if ry = 0, draws a circle)
    // - angle: Orientation angle (anti-clockwise)
    // - astart: Start angle
    // - afinish: Finish angle
    // - style: Style of ellipse (draw and/or fill: D, F, DF, FD, C (D + close))
    // - line_style: Line style for ellipse. Array like for SetLineStyle
    // - fill_color: Fill color. Array with components (red, green, blue)
    // - nSeg: Ellipse is made up of nSeg Bézier curves
    function Ellipse($x0, $y0, $rx, $ry = 0, $angle = 0, $astart = 0, $afinish = 360, $style = '', $line_style = null, $fill_color = null, $nSeg = 8) {
        if ($rx) {
            if (!(false === strpos($style, 'F')) && $fill_color) {
                list($r, $g, $b) = $fill_color;
                $this->SetFillColor($r, $g, $b);
            }
            switch ($style) {
                case 'F':
                    $op = 'f';
                    $line_style = null;
                    break;
                case 'FD': case 'DF':
                    $op = 'B';
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    $op = 's'; // small 's' means closing the path as well
                    break;
                default:
                    $op = 'S';
                    break;
            }
            if ($line_style)
                $this->SetLineStyle($line_style);
            if (!$ry)
                $ry = $rx;
            $rx *= $this->k;
            $ry *= $this->k;
            if ($nSeg < 2)
                $nSeg = 2;

            $astart = deg2rad((float) $astart);
            $afinish = deg2rad((float) $afinish);
            $totalAngle = $afinish - $astart;

            $dt = $totalAngle/$nSeg;
            $dtm = $dt/3;

            $x0 *= $this->k;
            $y0 = ($this->h - $y0) * $this->k;
            if ($angle != 0) {
                $a = -deg2rad((float) $angle);
                $this->_out(sprintf('q %.2F %.2F %.2F %.2F %.2F %.2F cm', cos($a), -1 * sin($a), sin($a), cos($a), $x0, $y0));
                $x0 = 0;
                $y0 = 0;
            }

            $t1 = $astart;
            $a0 = $x0 + ($rx * cos($t1));
            $b0 = $y0 + ($ry * sin($t1));
            $c0 = -$rx * sin($t1);
            $d0 = $ry * cos($t1);
            $this->_Point($a0 / $this->k, $this->h - ($b0 / $this->k));
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $nSeg; $i++) {
                // Draw this bit of the total curve
                $t1 = ($i * $dt) + $astart;
                $a1 = $x0 + ($rx * cos($t1));
                $b1 = $y0 + ($ry * sin($t1));
                $c1 = -$rx * sin($t1);
                $d1 = $ry * cos($t1);
                $this->_Curve(($a0 + ($c0 * $dtm)) / $this->k,
                            $this->h - (($b0 + ($d0 * $dtm)) / $this->k),
                            ($a1 - ($c1 * $dtm)) / $this->k,
                            $this->h - (($b1 - ($d1 * $dtm)) / $this->k),
                            $a1 / $this->k,
                            $this->h - ($b1 / $this->k));
                $a0 = $a1;
                $b0 = $b1;
                $c0 = $c1;
                $d0 = $d1;
            }
            $this->_out($op);
            if ($angle !=0)
                $this->_out('Q');
        }
    }

    // Draws a circle
    // Parameters:
    // - x0, y0: Center point
    // - r: Radius
    // - astart: Start angle
    // - afinish: Finish angle
    // - style: Style of circle (draw and/or fill) (D, F, DF, FD, C (D + close))
    // - line_style: Line style for circle. Array like for SetLineStyle
    // - fill_color: Fill color. Array with components (red, green, blue)
    // - nSeg: Ellipse is made up of nSeg Bézier curves
    function Circle($x0, $y0, $r, $astart = 0, $afinish = 360, $style = '', $line_style = null, $fill_color = null, $nSeg = 8) {
        $this->Ellipse($x0, $y0, $r, 0, 0, $astart, $afinish, $style, $line_style, $fill_color, $nSeg);
    }

    // Draws a polygon
    // Parameters:
    // - p: Points. Array with values x0, y0, x1, y1,..., x(np-1), y(np - 1)
    // - style: Style of polygon (draw and/or fill) (D, F, DF, FD)
    // - line_style: Line style. Array with one of this index
    //   . all: Line style of all lines. Array like for SetLineStyle
    //   . 0..np-1: Line style of each line. Item is 0 (not line) or like for SetLineStyle
    // - fill_color: Fill color. Array with components (red, green, blue)
    function Polygon($p, $style = '', $line_style = null, $fill_color = null) {
        $np = count($p) / 2;
        if (!(false === strpos($style, 'F')) && $fill_color) {
            list($r, $g, $b) = $fill_color;
            $this->SetFillColor($r, $g, $b);
        }
        switch ($style) {
            case 'F':
                $line_style = null;
                $op = 'f';
                break;
            case 'FD': case 'DF':
                $op = 'B';
                break;
            default:
                $op = 'S';
                break;
        }
        $draw = true;
        if ($line_style)
            if (isset($line_style['all']))
                $this->SetLineStyle($line_style['all']);
            else { // 0 .. (np - 1), op = {B, S}
                $draw = false;
                if ('B' == $op) {
                    $op = 'f';
                    $this->_Point($p[0], $p[1]);
                    for ($i = 2; $i < ($np * 2); $i = $i + 2)
                        $this->_Line($p[$i], $p[$i + 1]);
                    $this->_Line($p[0], $p[1]);
                    $this->_out($op);
                }
                $p[$np * 2] = $p[0];
                $p[($np * 2) + 1] = $p[1];
                for ($i = 0; $i < $np; $i++)
                    if (!empty($line_style[$i]))
                        $this->Line($p[$i * 2], $p[($i * 2) + 1], $p[($i * 2) + 2], $p[($i * 2) + 3], $line_style[$i]);
            }

        if ($draw) {
            $this->_Point($p[0], $p[1]);
            for ($i = 2; $i < ($np * 2); $i = $i + 2)
                $this->_Line($p[$i], $p[$i + 1]);
            $this->_Line($p[0], $p[1]);
            $this->_out($op);
        }
    }

    // Draws a regular polygon
    // Parameters:
    // - x0, y0: Center point
    // - r: Radius of circumscribed circle
    // - ns: Number of sides
    // - angle: Orientation angle (anti-clockwise)
    // - circle: Draw circumscribed circle or not
    // - style: Style of polygon (draw and/or fill) (D, F, DF, FD)
    // - line_style: Line style. Array with one of this index
    //   . all: Line style of all lines. Array like for SetLineStyle
    //   . 0..ns-1: Line style of each line. Item is 0 (not line) or like for SetLineStyle
    // - fill_color: Fill color. Array with components (red, green, blue)
    // - circle_style: Style of circumscribed circle (draw and/or fill) (D, F, DF, FD) (if draw)
    // - circle_line_style: Line style for circumscribed circle. Array like for SetLineStyle (if draw)
    // - circle_fill_color: Fill color for circumscribed circle. Array with components (red, green, blue) (if draw fill circle)
    function RegularPolygon($x0, $y0, $r, $ns, $angle = 0, $circle = false, $style = '', $line_style = null, $fill_color = null, $circle_style = '', $circle_line_style = null, $circle_fill_color = null) {
        if ($ns < 3)
            $ns = 3;
        if ($circle)
            $this->Circle($x0, $y0, $r, 0, 360, $circle_style, $circle_line_style, $circle_fill_color);
        $p = null;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $ns; $i++) {
            $a = $angle + ($i * 360 / $ns);
            $a_rad = deg2rad((float) $a);
            $p[] = $x0 + ($r * sin($a_rad));
            $p[] = $y0 + ($r * cos($a_rad));
        }
        $this->Polygon($p, $style, $line_style, $fill_color);
    }

    // Draws a star polygon
    // Parameters:
    // - x0, y0: Center point
    // - r: Radius of circumscribed circle
    // - nv: Number of vertices
    // - ng: Number of gaps (ng % nv = 1 => regular polygon)
    // - angle: Orientation angle (anti-clockwise)
    // - circle: Draw circumscribed circle or not
    // - style: Style of polygon (draw and/or fill) (D, F, DF, FD)
    // - line_style: Line style. Array with one of this index
    //   . all: Line style of all lines. Array like for SetLineStyle
    //   . 0..n-1: Line style of each line. Item is 0 (not line) or like for SetLineStyle
    // - fill_color: Fill color. Array with components (red, green, blue)
    // - circle_style: Style of circumscribed circle (draw and/or fill) (D, F, DF, FD) (if draw)
    // - circle_line_style: Line style for circumscribed circle. Array like for SetLineStyle (if draw)
    // - circle_fill_color: Fill color for circumscribed circle. Array with components (red, green, blue) (if draw fill circle)
    function StarPolygon($x0, $y0, $r, $nv, $ng, $angle = 0, $circle = false, $style = '', $line_style = null, $fill_color = null, $circle_style = '', $circle_line_style = null, $circle_fill_color = null) {
        if ($nv < 2)
            $nv = 2;
        if ($circle)
            $this->Circle($x0, $y0, $r, 0, 360, $circle_style, $circle_line_style, $circle_fill_color);
        $p2 = null;
        $visited = null;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $nv; $i++) {
            $a = $angle + ($i * 360 / $nv);
            $a_rad = deg2rad((float) $a);
            $p2[] = $x0 + ($r * sin($a_rad));
            $p2[] = $y0 + ($r * cos($a_rad));
            $visited[] = false;
        }
        $p = null;
        $i = 0;
        do {
            $p[] = $p2[$i * 2];
            $p[] = $p2[($i * 2) + 1];
            $visited[$i] = true;
            $i += $ng;
            $i %= $nv;
        } while (!$visited[$i]);
        $this->Polygon($p, $style, $line_style, $fill_color);
    }

    // Draws a rounded rectangle
    // Parameters:
    // - x, y: Top left corner
    // - w, h: Width and height
    // - r: Radius of the rounded corners
    // - round_corner: Draws rounded corner or not. String with a 0 (not rounded i-corner) or 1 (rounded i-corner) in i-position. Positions are, in order and begin to 0: top left, top right, bottom right and bottom left
    // - style: Style of rectangle (draw and/or fill) (D, F, DF, FD)
    // - border_style: Border style of rectangle. Array like for SetLineStyle
    // - fill_color: Fill color. Array with components (red, green, blue)
    function RoundedRect($x, $y, $w, $h, $r, $round_corner = '1111', $style = '', $border_style = null, $fill_color = null) {
        if ('0000' == $round_corner) // Not rounded
            $this->Rect($x, $y, $w, $h, $style, $border_style, $fill_color);
        else { // Rounded
            if (!(false === strpos($style, 'F')) && $fill_color) {
                list($red, $g, $b) = $fill_color;
                $this->SetFillColor($red, $g, $b);
            }
            switch ($style) {
                case 'F':
                    $border_style = null;
                    $op = 'f';
                    break;
                case 'FD': case 'DF':
                    $op = 'B';
                    break;
                default:
                    $op = 'S';
                    break;
            }
            if ($border_style)
                $this->SetLineStyle($border_style);

            $MyArc = 4 / 3 * (sqrt(2) - 1);

            $this->_Point($x + $r, $y);
            $xc = $x + $w - $r;
            $yc = $y + $r;
            $this->_Line($xc, $y);
            if ($round_corner[0])
                $this->_Curve($xc + ($r * $MyArc), $yc - $r, $xc + $r, $yc - ($r * $MyArc), $xc + $r, $yc);
            else
                $this->_Line($x + $w, $y);

            $xc = $x + $w - $r ;
            $yc = $y + $h - $r;
            $this->_Line($x + $w, $yc);

            if ($round_corner[1])
                $this->_Curve($xc + $r, $yc + ($r * $MyArc), $xc + ($r * $MyArc), $yc + $r, $xc, $yc + $r);
            else
                $this->_Line($x + $w, $y + $h);

            $xc = $x + $r;
            $yc = $y + $h - $r;
            $this->_Line($xc, $y + $h);
            if ($round_corner[2])
                $this->_Curve($xc - ($r * $MyArc), $yc + $r, $xc - $r, $yc + ($r * $MyArc), $xc - $r, $yc);
            else
                $this->_Line($x, $y + $h);

            $xc = $x + $r;
            $yc = $y + $r;
            $this->_Line($x, $yc);
            if ($round_corner[3])
                $this->_Curve($xc - $r, $yc - ($r * $MyArc), $xc - ($r * $MyArc), $yc - $r, $xc, $yc - $r);
            else {
                $this->_Line($x, $y);
                $this->_Line($x + $r, $y);
            }
            $this->_out($op);
        }
    }

    /* PRIVATE METHODS */

    // Sets a draw point
    // Parameters:
    // - x, y: Point
    function _Point($x, $y) {
        $this->_out(sprintf('%.2F %.2F m', $x * $this->k, ($this->h - $y) * $this->k));
    }

    // Draws a line from last draw point
    // Parameters:
    // - x, y: End point
    function _Line($x, $y) {
        $this->_out(sprintf('%.2F %.2F l', $x * $this->k, ($this->h - $y) * $this->k));
    }

    // Draws a Bézier curve from last draw point
    // Parameters:
    // - x1, y1: Control point 1
    // - x2, y2: Control point 2
    // - x3, y3: End point
    function _Curve($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $x3, $y3) {
        $this->_out(sprintf('%.2F %.2F %.2F %.2F %.2F %.2F c', $x1 * $this->k, ($this->h - $y1) * $this->k, $x2 * $this->k, ($this->h - $y2) * $this->k, $x3 * $this->k, ($this->h - $y3) * $this->k));
    }

}

?>
```

Don't forget to add `require_once('FPDF/fpdf.php');` and `require_once('FPDI/fpdi.php');` at the top of the page assuming you have this directory structure:

[image]

Then with code in `index.php` instead of extending the class `FPDI` we can directly extend `PDF_Draw`. This way the code we add earlier still work but now we can use new methods like `Line()`, `Curve()`, `Rect()` etc...

Here is the full `index.php` code:

```
<?php
require_once('draw.php');

// path of PDF file
$fullPathToFile = "sample.pdf";

class PDF extends PDF_Draw {

    .
    .
    .

}

// initiate PDF
$pdf = new PDF();

// go to first page
$pdf->nextPage();

// add content to current page
$pdf->SetFont("helvetica", "", 20);
$pdf->SetTextColor(220, 20, 60);
$pdf->Text(50, 20, "I should not be here!");

// move to next page and add content
$pdf->nextPage();

$pdf->SetFont("arial", "", 15);

$style = array('width' => 0.5, 'cap' => 'butt', 'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => '10,20,5,10', 'phase' => 10, 'color' => array(255, 0, 0));
$style2 = array('width' => 0.5, 'cap' => 'butt', 'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => 0, 'color' => array(255, 0, 0));
$style3 = array('width' => 1, 'cap' => 'round', 'join' => 'round', 'dash' => '2,10', 'color' => array(255, 0, 0));
$style4 = array('L' => 0,
                'T' => array('width' => 0.25, 'cap' => 'butt', 'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => '20,10', 'phase' => 10, 'color' => array(100, 100, 255)),
                'R' => array('width' => 0.50, 'cap' => 'round', 'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => 0, 'color' => array(50, 50, 127)),
                'B' => array('width' => 0.75, 'cap' => 'square', 'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => '30,10,5,10'));
$style5 = array('width' => 0.25, 'cap' => 'butt', 'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => 0, 'color' => array(0, 0, 0));
$style6 = array('width' => 0.5, 'cap' => 'butt', 'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => '10,10', 'color' => array(0, 255, 0));
$style7 = array('width' => 0.5, 'cap' => 'butt', 'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => 0, 'color' => array(200, 200, 0));

// Line
$pdf->Text(5, 7, 'Line');
$pdf->Line(5, 10, 80, 30, $style);

// Rect
$pdf->Text(100, 7, 'Rectangle');
$pdf->Rect(100, 10, 40, 20, 'DF', $style4, array(220, 220, 200));

// Curve
$pdf->Text(5, 37, 'Curve');
$pdf->Curve(5, 40, 30, 55, 70, 45, 60, 75, null, $style6);

// Circle and ellipse
$pdf->Text(5, 82, 'Circle and ellipse');
$pdf->SetLineStyle($style5);
$pdf->Circle(25,105,20);

// Polygon
$pdf->Text(5, 132, 'Polygon');
$pdf->SetLineStyle(array('width' => 0.5, 'cap' => 'butt', 'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => 0, 'color' => array(0, 0, 0)));
$pdf->Polygon(array(5,135,45,135,15,165));

// Regular polygon
$pdf->Text(5, 172, 'Regular polygon');
$pdf->SetLineStyle($style5);
$pdf->RegularPolygon(20, 190, 15, 6, 0, 1, 'F');

// Star polygon
$pdf->Text(5, 212, 'Star polygon');
$pdf->SetLineStyle($style5);
$pdf->StarPolygon(20, 230, 15, 20, 3, 0, 1, 'F');

// Rounded rectangle
$pdf->Text(5, 252, 'Rounded rectangle');
$pdf->SetLineStyle(array('width' => 0.5, 'cap' => 'butt', 'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => 0, 'color' => array(0, 0, 0)));
$pdf->RoundedRect(5, 255, 40, 30, 3.50, '1111', 'DF');

$pdf->SetTextColor(65, 105, 225);
$pdf->Text(50, 20, "Me neither!!!");

//show the PDF in page
$pdf->Output();
```

DEMO!
[image]

Comment: I have updated my answer with the complete guide to adding drawings to an existing PDF using PHP

Answer (score 5):

[TCPDF (tcpdf.org)](https://tcpdf.org/) seems to handle [PDF graphics methods](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_012/).

Cf. [`examples/example_012.php`](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/009f2304c3a9c8152b89a5321a8825f250911dc3/examples/example_012.php):

```
// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// Line
$pdf->Text(5, 4, 'Line examples');
$pdf->Line(5, 10, 80, 30, $style);
$pdf->Line(5, 10, 5, 30, $style2);
$pdf->Line(5, 10, 80, 10, $style3);
// Rect
$pdf->Text(100, 4, 'Rectangle examples');
$pdf->Rect(100, 10, 40, 20, 'DF', $style4, array(220, 220, 200));
$pdf->Rect(145, 10, 40, 20, 'D', array('all' => $style3));
```

And its [GitHub project `tecnickcom/tcpdf`](https://github.com/tecnickcom/tcpdf) indicated being 100% PHP.
However, [this search](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=open%20pdf&type=) shows it can create and modify a new PDF document. It might not be able to open and modify an existing one.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.fpdf.org
If You want to draw using `x, y coordinates` 
[fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org) as well as [tcpdf](https://tcpdf.org/) can be useful for you.

```
global $title;
    // Calculate width
    $w = $this->GetStringWidth($title)+6;
    $this->SetX((210-$w)/2);
    // Colors of frame, background and text
    $this->SetDrawColor(0,80,180);
    $this->SetFillColor(230,230,0);
    $this->SetTextColor(220,50,50);
    // Thickness of frame (1 mm)
    $this->SetLineWidth(1);
    // Title
    $this->Cell($w,9,$title,1,1,'C',true);
    // Line break
    $this->Ln(10);
}
```